# Fluent-NHibernate : how to map one-to-many relationship into 3 tables (many-to-many, kinda)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have to 2 entities like this:

```
class A
{
   int id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}

class B
{
   int id { get; set; }
   A RefToA { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I map this 2 classes so that i would have 3 tables like this:

- table A with 2 columns: id and name
- table B with 2 columns: id and name
- table AB with 2 columns: AId and BId

Comment: Why do you need the ref table (AB) if you want a one-to-many?

Comment: because most of the time, almost always that FK column created by one-to-many is going to be null

Comment: Then why doesnt table be have the following column `AId REFERENCES A NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correct you are creating a ref table because you want the reference to be nullable. If that is the case, you do not need a ref table. Simply set the FK in table b as nullable. Then you can map it a simple reference. Then you would have tables like this:

- table A with 2 columns: id and name
- table B with 2 columns: id, name and
  Aid (nullable)

And you can map it like this:

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
  public AMap()
  {
      Id(x => x.Id); 
      Map(x => x.Name);
  }
}

public class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
  public BMap()
  {
     Id(x => x.Id); 
     Map(x => x.Name);
     References(x => x.RefToA);
  }
}
```

**Update**

There is no way of mapping this how you want in nhibernate (and no other orm for that matter). The reason for this is quite simple: it violates quite a few rules and there is never a reason to do it this way. The correct way to do this is to have a nullable fk reference in table b. That is how you represent a reference in a sql database. It is simply bad design to use many-to-many when you mean one-to-many and it will most certainly give you trouble later on.

Comment: it's not because it is nullable, it's because i don't want it to be present in that table

Comment: I can't see why? What would that gain you?

Comment: I'm not going to have a FK column in my table that is almost always going to be null

Comment: What is wrong with References(x => x.RefToA).CanBeNull(); This is probably the only way you are going to get close to what you want with fluent nhibernate. I think it might be time for a redesign.

Comment: In my opinion you should rethink that a little bit. There is no way to map a many-to-many as a one-to-many in nhibernate (neither should there). It would do you no harm in having that extra field in that table. But if you would have it as a ref table you would always have a join.

Comment: I kinda agree with you, my team leader wants it that way, he said it has something to do with Boyce-Code normal form, that says that there should be no null values or references or something

Comment: I would strongly argue against him on this one. The way he suggest breaks a lot more patterns and rules then having a nullable FK. What would happen if one B has references to two different A's? You can work against this in your application. But that forces the application to handle data integrity. That is a job for the database.

Comment: There is no harm in having an extra field, but there is a harm having a dozen of extra mostly null field - and this situation can occur if many objects can be associated with a particular class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical ManyToMany relationship.  In FluentNHibernate you would use

```
HasManyToMany<T>();
```

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#HasManyToMany_.2F_many-to-many

Comment: I know that I can do this as a simple ManyToMany relationship, but this will require me to put a list in my entity instead of a simple reference

Answer (score 1):

what you want is References(x => x.RefToA);

The following below is from the fluent nhibernate documenation.

References / many-to-one

References is for creating many-to-one relationships between two entities; you're referencing another entity, so you use the References method. A reference is to a single instance of an entity

**http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping**

Comment: yes but this will create a FK id Column, and I don't want that, I need a 3rd table instead

Comment: Then what you want is HasOne(x => x.RefToA);

any reason you don't want a PK for the thrid table? legacy?

Comment: I don't need another FK column in my table because most of the time this column is going to be null, so that's why I want to put it into a 3rd table, I could have done it with HasManyToMany but with this approach I would have had to write MyCollectionProperty[0] all the time (because it can be no more than one)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be mapping a one-to-many relation as a many-to-many relation, then forcing it to be a one-to-many.  Its bad design, and does not promote data integrity.  If I were you, I would create your tables as follows

```
CREATE TABLE A(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    --Your other columns
)

CREATE TABLE B(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    AId INT REFERENCES A NULL,
    --Your other columns
)
```

That way, you can map them the way you want to in Fluent NHibernate, or any other ORM.